# IIS automatically making sub folders into applications, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We have an Application that has lots of subfolders (each one compiled up in separate projects in VS as classes)

When you first load up the .sln file it is creating the virtual folders etc, but it is adding an application for each subfolder which prevents our code working. As it is expecting it to be one application so we have to go through the folders removing the applications added in error. 
Each subfolder has a web.config that contains the configuration for the entityFramework and other required links, could this be why it is being added as an application?
in Summary:

Why are these applications being automatically added?

How can we stop them being added automatically?

Comment: Did you include these files into your project? It sounds like something was added into webdeploy publish profile which cause IIS adding these applications